# Blocking Apk's from installing directly into BB10.2.1 updated devices

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I port my android apps for making bb10 builds . Since now from bb10.2.1 update blackberry has introduced a new concept wherein apk's can be directly installed and can be installed in BB10 devices if the manage apps in settings menu of the phone is made ON. My question is that I wanna restrict my users from doing so and not installing the apk's into bb10 . And take download my app only from appworld.

Has anyone faced and has fixed this issue kindly tell me on how to solve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Android behaviour, I don't think you can restrict users from doing so.

I haven't tried it on BlackBerry but from what you say, that option sounds analogue to the **Unknown sources** setting under **Security settings** on Android. If the user enables the installation of applications from unknown sources on their phone, there is now way to prevent the direct install of the apk (by adding something to your apk or any other way).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict it to BlackBerry World only. If they get the APK, they can load it directly this way. There may be other ways around it though.

If, for example, your app is for sale and people are side loading a pirated copy, you could change your app to be free, and put some advanced functionality in your app behind an in-app purchase. That way they'll be forced to go through the storefront at some point to pay. This takes bigger changes to your app though, and the IAP implementation is likely different between BBW and GPlay.

You could also put in a version check: when your app launches, it checks a special file on your web server to see what the latest version of the app is. If they don't have the latest version, it doesn't let them use the app until they upgrade. This won't prevent side loading or piracy outright, but you can put out updates often enough to make side loading very annoying. When they are roadblocked and told to get the new version, you can link directly to the storefront to encourage them to get the latest version there.

Thirdly, and lastly, if you port your app to a BlackBerry 10 native, cascades, or WebWorks app, the app file is fully protected and can't be pirated or extracted from BlackBerry World (since the platform is secure). That will 100% protect you from piracy on BlackBerry 10.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The answers you had given me would work only after installation wherein launching the app but I wanna restrict users from installing my apps from apk and to install only bar file i.e from BBW if you have any solution to that kindly provide